# error in download worldclim data using raster getData function

Tags: r, r-raster

Does anyone know if there is any change to worldclim website
I am trying to download weather data from worldclim using the
`getData` function from `raster` package but running into following error:

```
library(raster)

clim=getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=2.5) 

trying URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/bio_2-5m_bil.zip'
  Error in utils::download.file(url = aurl, destfile = fn, method = "auto",  : 
    cannot open URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/bio_2-5m_bil.zip'
  In addition: Warning message:
  In utils::download.file(url = aurl, destfile = fn, method = "auto",  :
    InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
```

My R session is

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default
```

Comment: there is one issue raised for [this](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/169)

Comment: I am still having this issue. and the link has been closed that arkun provided. I have put a comment there. Hope someone sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service has been restored. Please note that `raster::getData` will be retired in the future, as the data are also available through the`geodata` package.